# Data set for action recognition in trains

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, public-transport

I am working on a project for visual recognition of actions of people inside trains and metro stations. My aim is to detect abnormal behaviour.

I am looking for data from any kind of sensors that could be installed in trains, such as wide angle cameras, microphones and 3d sensors.

Does anyone know any relevant online data source?